# msi creation needs using cx_freeze in python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, cx-freeze

Suppose, I have written a code in python 2.7 . let's say i am using vlc player in my script and now i have created a msi file for my code so how to install "vlc player" in user's system during installation of msi file of my python code.

Please give the example of setup file of cx_freeze package which installs all the dependent softweare (like VLC) in the user's system during installation of msi of python code.

I just want to know where to add these dependencies (for installation) in setup file of cx_freeze.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know much about cx_freeze

well for my project i've used [pynsist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecvuq.png)

and this is really easy to make msi in this.

this is my instaalet.cfg file to run pynist 
[image]

you can check example [here](https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist)

Comment: can you please explain thru the example because i am new in python @Manan Kalariya

Comment: you can check the example in the answer. and also I've put my code too. i've done lot of research on this and out of all  options i chouse pynsist

Comment: if this answer solved your problem then you can always accept or upvote the answer @PythonLearner

Comment: i am asking the solution for cx_freeze.